# AngularJS can't read $http result in nested $http calls

Tags: angularjs

I have the following nested $http calls to two apis, problem I am facing is that I can't access outer $http call results from inner $http call even though outer $http call results is assigned to a separate variable. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here and how to fix it? Thanks

```
clientSvc.getInvoices(clientID).then(
    function(clientInvoices) {
        var invoiceID = '';

        for (var i=0; i < clientInvoices.Result.length; i++) {
            invoicesPromise.push(clientSvc.getAR(clientInvoices.Result[i].id).then(
                function(ARList) {

                           //This will always return 3
                           console.log(i);

                    //following line raises an error id of undefined...
                    invoiceID = clientInvoices.Result[i].id; 
                },
                function(status){
                    console.log(status);
                }
            ));
        }

        $q.all(invoicesPromise).then(function() {
            ....
        });
    },
    function(status){
        console.log(status);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You reference `i` from the closure, but its value changes in the loop; when the `then` success functions do get called, `i` is `clientInvoices.Result.length + 1`, which is why `clientInvoices.Result[i]` is undefined. Use a separate function e.g. as:

```
        for (var i=0; i < clientInvoices.Result.length; i++) {
            invoicesPromise.push(callNested(clientInvoices.Result[i].id));
        }

        function callNested(resultId) {
            return clientSvc.getAR(resultId).then(
                function(ARList) {
                    invoiceID = resultId; 
                },
                function(status){
                    console.log(status);
                }
            )
        }
```

Still though, you are assigning to the single-valued variable `invoiceID` many times; this will cause problems. Also, there is no `var invoicesPromise = [];` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've already var invoicesPromise = [] in code I just had to eliminate it in question as I thought to post only the code causing the problem

Comment: I've updated the question with a console.log(i) which was strange enough to always output 3....any thought why this could be?

Comment: Please note the use of $q.all for invoicesPromise possibly this is the reason for all of this?